# CSS DIV scrollbar and background with min-width

Tags: css

I have a header DIV which is 1400px wide and contains a background image which must always stay centered.

I have a site that needs to be 960px wide.

When I resize the browser (shrink it), I don't want any horizontal scrollbars until we hit 960px, but the larger width on the header/background is causing this.

Is it possible to stop all horizontal scrollbars on resize until 960px AND keep the background image in the header div centered??

Any help appreciated! Some code I set up here here for a quick test...

http://jsfiddle.net/gVuvk
The background image has a width of 1400px. I need the scrollbars to start at 960px - NOT 1400px. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

change `#header` width from fixed pixels to `100%`

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/wNSTD/3/

Comment: That worked for the example - but realise I've done something wrong...New version ehre - note that the image is now inline - and not a background.
Any way to do same min-width for a div with a wide image in it?

http://jsfiddle.net/wNSTD/5/

Comment: @lowercase you can use `#header img {width:100%}` this will fit the image in the width, but will resize the height also to keep aspect ratio.

Comment: thanks for the help but still not working when i run it with jquery.
New JSFiddle here which shows the jquery plugin running.
http://jsfiddle.net/gVuvk/
The background image has a width of 1400px. I need the scrollbars to start at 960px - NOT 1400px. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try fiddling with min-width, if that does not work, use margins, css `auto-margins` can be useful here. So, make the structure like this:

```
<style>
.center_image
{
  margin: auto auto; // or you can modify the x or y seperately
  background-image:url("somesite.jpg");
}
</style>

<div class="outer">
  <div class="center_image">
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of header to 100% and center the background image.

```
background: url(http://fade.com.au/test/bg-image.jpg) no-repeat center center;
width: 100%;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/post_erasmus/Hn6Zb/1/